# Endgame Fortresses

Tags: endgame

```
[fen "6r1/1p3k2/2rb1p1p/3NpP1P/PpPp2pR/1P1K2P1/4RP2/8 b - - 0 1"]
```

If Black holds his bishop on c5, rook on a8/a5 (if a5 is a threat), rook on g8 (protect g4) or the 8th rank, is there any way for White to break through?

If so, what would be the best defense for Black?

Black to move. He will play Rg5.

Comment: After Re4, pawn g4 is falling already and an invasion on g6 is imminent. Black can win pawn f5. I haven't done any concrete analysis, it might still be drawn, but one can hardly call that a fortress.

Comment: Whose turn is it?

Comment: Black to move. Sorry, he plays ...Rg5 here.

Comment: You can't really put the bishop on c5 and the rook on a5, because then Nc7-e6 will make you lose the g4-pawn longterm. But with Rg5, Ra5 and Bd6 I don't see any way for white to make progress.

Comment: After Black plays Rg5, then Re4 may be too optimistic for White. Black plays Rxf5 and White must defend against Rxf2 followed by either Rb2 or Rf3+. If White ignores those threats and plays Rxg4 and Rg6, then Black has Bf8 as a defense.

Comment: I think this position is very complicated, and needs a concrete analysis for a good amount of time. White has some risky moves which can lead to win or loss. And calculating them is not easy. I would answer this question but, I can't dedicate that much time to analyze this position.

Answer (score 1):

I believe if white breaks through, then black has some counter play chances on the queen side. For instance:

```
[FEN "6r1/1p3k2/2rb1p1p/3NpP1P/PpPp2pR/1P1K2P1/4RP2/8 b - - 0 1"]

1... Rg5 2. Re4 Rxf5 3. Rhxg4 Rf3+ 4. Ke2 Rxb3 5. Rg6 Bf8 6. f4 Bg7 7. fxe5 fxe5 8. Reg4 Bf8
```

and white's queen side pawns are gone and black has serious threats.

Otherwise if white try to holds on his pawns, there is no way to make any progress and the game will be draw.